# How to convert python list to JSON array?

Tags: python, arrays, json, django, arraylist

If I have python list like

```py
pyList=[‘x@x.x’,’y@y.y’]
```

And I want it to convert it to json array and add `{}` around every object, it should be like that :

```py
arrayJson=[{“email”:”x@x.x”},{“ email”:”y@y.y”}]
```

any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using built-in [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) module

```
import json

arrayJson = json.dumps([{"email": item} for item in pyList])
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide a link from the `docs`. :); https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/json.html?highlight=json#module-json

Answer (score 0):

Try to Google this kind of stuff first. :)

```
import json

array = [1, 2, 3]
jsonArray = json.dumps(array)
```

By the way, the result you asked for can not be achieved with the list you provided.

You need to use python dictionaries to get json objects. The conversion is like below

```
Python -> JSON
list -> array
dictionary -> object
```

And here is the link to the docs
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

pip install jsonwhatever.

You should try it, you can put anything on it

```
from jsonwhatever import jsonwhatever as jw

pyList=['x@x.x','y@y.y']

jsonwe = jw.JsonWhatEver()

mytr = jsonwe.jsonwhatever('my_custom_list', pyList)

print(mytr)
```